# Convert JSON object back to String for Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I'm trying to write a recursive function that, if it contains "expr" as a key instead of "number" it will feed that section of the JSON back into the function. My code is the following:

```
var result = 0;

function calc(str) {
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty("expr")) {
        var temp = obj.expr;
        JSON.stringify(temp);
        calc(temp);
    }
    if (obj.op == "add") {
        var i = parseInt(obj.number);
        result += i;    
    } else if(obj.op == "subtract") {
        var i = parseInt(obj.number);
        result -= i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I'm getting a Syntax Error saying "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1." Does Stringify not reformat it back into a string? If so, how would I go about that?

My input is something like the following:

> result = calc('{"op" : "add", "number" : 5}'); 
>   result = calc('{"op" : "subtract", "number" : 2}'); 
>   result = calc('{"op" : "add", "number" : 19}'); 
>   result = calc('{"op": "subtract", "expr" : {"op" : "add", "number" : 15}}');

Comment: can you please share the json

Comment: `JSON.stringify` returns a string, it doesn't modify its argument. The mistake is the line above `calc(temp)`

Comment: look at my answer

Comment: Not: You are not converting a "JSON object" to a string. You are converting a JavaScript object to JSON.

Comment: @jackarms _"it doesn't modify its argument."_ Note, `JSON.stringify()` can modify the argument passed to return a different result than argument as a string

Comment: That is true, I could have been more clear that with only one argument it does not modify the argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figured out.

```
var result = 0;

function calc(str) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(str);
    var i = parseInt(obj.number);
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty("expr")) {
        var temp = obj.expr;
        temp = JSON.stringify(temp);
        var i = calc(temp);
    }     
    if (obj.op == "add") {
        result += i;
    } else if(obj.op == "subtract") {
        result -= i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this:

```
function calc(str) {

    var res = 0;
    var obj = (typeof str =="string") ? JSON.parse(str) : str;

    if(obj.hasOwnProperty("expr")) obj.number = calc(obj.expr);

    switch(obj.op){
      case "add":   
          res += +obj.number;
      break;
      case "subtract":
          res -= +obj.number;
      break;
    }    
    return res;
}
```

Input

```
var result = 0;
result += calc('{"op" : "add", "number" : 5}'); 
result += calc('{"op" : "subtract", "number" : 2}'); 
result += calc('{"op" : "add", "number" : 19}'); 
result += calc('{"op": "subtract", "expr" : {"op" : "add", "number" : 15}}');
```